# Is the ratio of sequences not being bounded a necessary condition for a sequence to not be Big-Oh?

Tags: numerical-methods

This is more for clarification than anything else, in my text we define:

**Definition:** We say $x_n = \mathcal{O}(\alpha_n)$ if there are constants $C$ and $n_0$ such that $|x_n| \leq C|\alpha_n|$ when $n \geq n_0$.

Am I right in saying that the ratio
$\dfrac{|x_n|}{| \alpha_n |} \leq C$, where $\alpha_n \neq 0$ is bounded as $n\to\infty$ for $x_n = \mathcal{O}(\alpha_n)$ as a necessary condition.

So that if $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{ |x_n|}{|\alpha_n|} = \infty$$
then $x_n \neq \mathcal{O}(\alpha_n)$.

Comment: Technically, 0 is O(0). But otherwise yes.

Comment: Yes, although you should write $|x_n|\leq C|\alpha_n$| as $\alpha_n$ may be $0$ for some $n.$

Comment: a less math talk about it : https://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation/

Comment: There are many cases in between where such a limit does not exist (even in the form of divergence to $∞$), while a classification into $O(α_n)$ or not is still possible.